# Varying definitions of symmetric and selfadjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

There seems to be some disagreement (at least when consulting textbooks), what constitutes a symmetric operator and what constitutes a selfadjoint operator (of course, only the unbounded case is of relevance).

For example Lax, in his "Functional Analysis" book, says on pp. 354 that a symmetric operator $M:H\rightarrow H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is one that fulfills $\left< Mx,y \right>=\left<x,My \right>$ for all $x,y\in H$ and on pp. 377 defines a selfadjoint operator to be an operator $M:D\subseteq H\rightarrow H$ with a dense subset $D$, such that $\left<Mx,y \right>=\left<x,My \right>$ for all $x,y\in D$.
One the other hand, in Rudins book on pp. 331 the names for these properties are reversed, as they are also in Kreyszigs book (pp. 533)

Now this question isn't about what "ultimately" would mean for an operator to be symmetric resp. selfadjoint since there seems to be no agreement upon this issue.
But the majority of books (and some of the answers on math.SE concerning these definitions, as  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38387/distinguishing-between-symmetric-hermitian-and-self-adjoint-operators) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788412/the-difference-between-hermitian-symmetric-and-self-adjoint-operators) one) seem to indicate, that the majority is on Rudin side.
My question therefore is, what prompted the "Lax"-side to switch the definitions ? Is there any advantage to this ?

**EDIT** Here are the quotes from these books:

Kreyszig (1978):

> **Definition** Let $T:\mathscr{D}(T)\longrightarrow H$ be a linear operator which is densely defined in a complex Hilbert space $H$. Then $T$ is calles a *symmetric linear operator* if for all $x,y\in \mathscr{D}(T)$, $$\left< Tx,y\right>=\left<x,Ty\right>$$

$ $

> **Definition** Let $T:\mathscr{D}(T)\longrightarrow H$ be a linear operator which is densely defined in a complex Hilbert space $H$. Then $T$ is calles a *self-adjoint linear operator* if $$T=T^*.$$

Lax (2002):

> In this chapter we study operators $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{M}}$ that map a complex Hilbert space $H$ into itself, that are bounded, and that are *symmetric* in the sense that $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{M}}^*=\boldsymbol{\operatorname{M}}$. According to the definition of adjoint this means that for all $x$ and $y$ in $H$ $$\left<\boldsymbol{\operatorname{M}}x,y\right>=\left<x,\boldsymbol{\operatorname{M}}y\right>.$$

$ $

> **Definition** Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space. $D$ a dense subspace of $H$, and $A$ a linear operator defined on $D$. The adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ is the operator whose domain $D^*$ consists of all vectors $v$ in $H$ for which there is a vector denoted as $A^*v$ in $H$ such that $$\left<Au,v\right>=\left<u,A^*v\right>$$holds for all $u$ in $D$. Since $D$ is dense, for any given $v$ there can only be one such vector $A^*v$. Clearly, $D^*$ is a linear subspace of $H$, and $A^*$is a linear operator on $D^*$. $A$ is called *self-adjoint* if $D^*=D$ and $A^*=A$.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the definitions you quote.  What you say is "symmetric according to Lax" is everywhere defined and hence (by Hellinger-Toeplitz) bounded.  And what you say is "self-adjoint according to Lax" is what people today call "symmetric".  *Neither* definition is what anyone today calls "self-adjoint".  Unfortunately I do not have any of the books you cite, but I think it might help a lot if you would transcribe their definitions verbatim, or even include a scan of the relevant pages.

Comment: Also, which editions of the books are you looking at?  The latest editions of Lax, Rudin and Kreyszig are from 2002, 1991 and 1989 respectively.  If the terminology wasn't standardized by those dates I'll eat anyone's hat.

Comment: @NateEldredge I updated my question with the according verbatim quotes. Lax indeed seems to defined "symmetric" only for bounded operators - which makes sense, since his "self-adjoint" typically is, as you mentioned, called "symmetric". (I do hope that I haven't mixed up the definitions between the two different books, since these vary in minor details and have wasted your and my time, but a cursory glance does seem to indication that my original transcription isn't flawed.)

Comment: No, I disagree.  Lax's actual definition of "self-adjoint" is the same as everyone else's.  It is not the same as everyone's definition of "symmetric", and it is not the same as what you claim in your second paragraph.

Comment: All this is totally standard, we just want to keep in mind that if $M$ is bounded ("Lax 2002"), then self-adjoint $\iff$ symmetric.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an erroneous reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, let me try to sort this out.

There is no disagreement between the definitions you quote.  However, your initial paraphrases of those definitions are not accurate.

You wrote:

> For example Lax, in his "Functional Analysis" book, says on pp. 354 that a symmetric operator $M:H\rightarrow H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is one that fulfills **[A]** $\left< Mx,y \right>=\left<x,My \right>$ for all $x,y\in H$ and on pp. 377 defines a selfadjoint operator to be an operator $M:D\subseteq H\rightarrow H$ with a dense subset $D$, such that **[B]** $\left<Mx,y \right>=\left<x,My \right>$ for all $x,y\in D$.

I have added the marks **[A]**, **[B]** for reference.

I say that your **[A]** is what everyone calls "symmetric and bounded", your **[B]** is what everyone calls "symmetric", and that neither of them is what anyone calls "self-adjoint".

Your definition **[A]** does match Lax's first definition; however, in that definition he is defining what it means for a *bounded* operator to be symmetric.  For a bounded operator defined on all of $H$, **[A]** and **[B]** are of course equivalent.

Your definition **[B]** *does not* match Lax's second definition; it is completely different.  The key point is the introduction of the new subspace $D^*$ which in general may be different from $D$; Lax's requirement that $D = D^*$ is crucial and by no means trivial.  Lax's second definition agrees with every other definition of "self-adjoint" (for unbounded operators) that I have ever seen.

Kreyszig's first definition matches your definition **[B]**, which as I claimed is what people call "symmetric".

Kreyszig's second definition matches neither your **[A]** nor **[B]**, but if you investigate his definition of $T^*$, I claim you will find it equivalent to Lax's second definition.  It is again the standard definition of "self-adjoint".

**Edit.** I'll address your added comments.

Let me first mention that when working with unbounded operators, one has to keep in mind that an unbounded operator is really a pair $(A,D)$ of an operator and its domain: a linear subspace $D \subset H$ and a linear map $A: D \to H$.  In particular, for two operators to be equal, they have to have the same domain.  The fact that people often just use the word "operator" and talk mostly about $A$ instead of $D$ tends to obscure this essential point.  For the rest of this answer, I'll write the operator and its domain explicitly.

So suppose $(A,D)$ is an unbounded operator and $D$ is dense (people say "$A$ is densely defined").  As you say, we define a new operator $(A^*, D^*)$, called the adjoint of $(A,D)$, as in Lax: $v \in D^*$ iff there is a vector $w_v \in H$ such that for every $u \in D$ we have $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, w_v \rangle$.  For each $v \in D^*$, if $w_v$ exists then it is unique, and we define $A^*v := w_v$.  We say $(A,D)$ is **self-adjoint** if $(A,D) = (A^*, D^*)$, i.e. $D=D^*$ and $A=A^*$.

It is true that we have the relationship
$$\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A^* v \rangle, \quad \forall u \in D, v \in D^* \quad \quad (\star)$$
But I want to emphasize that $(A^*, D^*)$ is not just *some* operator satisfying $(\star)$; it is the *specific* operator defined in the previous paragraph.  (In some sense, it is the operator satisfying $(\star)$ and having largest possible domain.)

Then, as you have argued, if $(A,D)$ is self-adjoint, then in particular **[B]** holds: we have $\langle Au, v \rangle = \langle u, A v \rangle$ for every $u,v \in D$.  That is to say, if $A$ is self-adjoint then it is symmetric.

**The converse is false**: a symmetric operator need not be self-adjoint.  Here is a typical counterexample.

Let $H = L^2([0,1])$, and let $D = C^2_c((0,1))$.  That is, $D$ consists of $C^2$ functions having compact support contained in $(0,1)$.  In particular, if $f \in D$ then $f$ and all its derivatives vanish at $0$ and $1$.  For $f \in D$, let $Af = f''$ be the second derivative of $f$.

Recall from calculus that for any $f,g \in C^2([0,1])$ we have, by integrating by parts twice:
$$\int_0^1 f''(x) g(x)\,dx = f'(1) g(1) - f'(0) g(0) - f(1)g'(1) + f(0)g'(0) + \int_0^1 f(x) g''(x)\,dx.$$
If $f,g \in D$, then all the boundary terms vanish and we have $\int_0^1 f''(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x) g''(x)\,dx$.  That is, for all $f,g \in D$, $\langle Af, g \rangle = \langle f, Ag \rangle$.  So $(A,D)$ is symmetric.

But I claim that $(A,D)$ is not self-adjoint; in particular, $D^*$ is a proper superset of $D$.  Indeed, we can see that if $f \in D$ and $g \in C^2([0,1])$, then again all boundary terms vanish and $\int_0^1 f''(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x) g''(x)\,dx$, i.e. $\langle Af, g \rangle = \langle f, g'' \rangle$.  So $g \in D^*$ and $A^* g = g''$.  Thus $C^2([0,1]) \subset D^*$: we see that $D^*$ contains functions which do not vanish at 0 and 1 and hence are not in $D$.  (In fact, $D^*$ is the Sobolev space $H^2([0,1])$, though it takes a little more work to show this.)  So $(A,D) \ne (A^*, D^*)$.

Moreover, $(A^*, D^*)$ is not symmetric.  Take for example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$.  Since $f,g$ are $C^2$ they are contained in $D^*$ and $A^*f = f'' = 0$, $A^*g = g'' = 2$.  Then you can check that $\langle A^* f, g \rangle = 0$ while $\langle f, A^*g \rangle = 1$.

(Actually, you can show that if $(A,D)$ and $(A^*, D^*)$ are both symmetric, then $(A^*, D^*)$ is self-adjoint, and in fact $(A^*, D^*)$ equals the closure of $(A,D)$.  In this case $(A,D)$ is said to be **essentially self-adjoint**.)

Comment: Good-and-clear. Perhaps we should also admit that it is very hard to _guess_, from the terminology "symmetric" or "hermitian" or "self-adjoint" what the insinuated distinctions might be. That is, this terminology is not so good, whether or not it's standard. E.g., for bounded operators, one _might_ (reasonbly!) think that "symmetric" might mean $\mathbb C$-symmetric, as opposed to $\mathbb C$-sesquilinear? Equally plausible, why wouldn't "symmetric", "hermitian", and "self-adjoint" be approximately synonyms? That kind of thing.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't quite understand why my definition [B] doesn't match Lax's. I think it's a case of ambiguous wording, but here's how I got to [B] from Lax's definition: We have a *fixed* set $D$ and an operator $A$ defined on it. Then we construct somehow an set $D^*$ and an operator $A^*$ defined on it, such that by construction $$\left<Au,v\right>=\left<u,A^*v\right>\quad\quad (\star )$$for all $u\in D$ and $v\in D^*$. Then we proceed by calling $A$ self-adjoint, if this construction is such that $D=D^*$ and $A^*=A$, i.e. $D^*$ and $A^*$ equal our initial fixed set and operator. [...]

Comment: @NateEldrige [...] Therefore we can in $(\star)$ substitute $A^∗$ for our original $A$ and $D^∗$ for $D$ so that the seld-adjoint requirement becomes
$$\left< Au,v\right> =\left< u,Av \right>$$
for all $u,v\in D$, as I wrote in my definition.

Comment: Could someone please help me out with this ? I can't accept this answer, until I sort this out.

Comment: @temo: I'll try to add some more, though it could be a few days before I get to it. But in short: it is true that if A is self-adjoint then your [B] holds. But the converse is false: an operator may satisfy [B] and not be self-adjoint.

Comment: @temo: See my edit now.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your elaborate edit. Because you put so much work in it and really explain the issue to me, I'm going to award you 50 points